# OpenGL Memory leak with more deletes than allocations

Tags: opengl, memory-leaks

I'm being asked to maintain a library that I did not write. I have an application that is doing many different views. They could be at different sizes (width/height) and they could be of different scenes and they certainly are different perspectives. Typically the code goes

```
initialize view
set resolution of view 
do stuff to view
clear view
```

This is repeated several times w/in a single process.

Windows Task Manager shows there is a memory leak. The application is designed around a C layer calling a C++ object called a render. The code in ** represents the C layer. All else is within the object.

initialize new view looks something like

```
**if there is an old render delete it.**
{
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &this->vao);

    glDeleteBuffers(1, &this->positionBuffer);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &this->fbo);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &this->rbo);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &this->ibo);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &this->dbo);    
}       

**Create new render**
this->rbo = NULL;
this->fbo = NULL;
this->ibo = NULL;
this->dbo = NULL;
initialize this render's scalars.
```

set resolution of view goes

```
glDeleteBuffers(1, &this->rbo);
glDeleteBuffers(1, &this->fbo);
glDeleteBuffers(1, &this->dbo);

glGenRenderbuffers(1, &this->rbo);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, this->rbo);
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RGBA32F, width, height);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, 0);
error check

glGenRenderbuffers(1, &this->dbo);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, this->dbo);
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT32F, width, height);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, 0);
error check

glGenFramebuffers(1, &this->fbo);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, this->fbo);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, this->rbo);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, this->dbo);
error check
```

and clear view looks like

```
glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &this->vao);

glDeleteBuffers(1, &this->positionBuffer);
glDeleteBuffers(1, &this->fbo);
glDeleteBuffers(1, &this->rbo);
glDeleteBuffers(1, &this->ibo);
glDeleteBuffers(1, &this->dbo);
```

Reading suggests this is not the optimal way to use a GPU, but looking at the code it seems to me that it should work. They were persistent :)  I see memory being allocated in set resolution of view, but that memory looks like it is released, well, pretty much everywhere. If that's the case....why the leak? Am I overlooking something obvious?

I have read the similarly phrased questions and don't see an answer. I've got far more deletes than allocations here.

Comment: Have you tried to attach a OpenGL debugger (codeXL, nsight) to see if really all opengl objects are freed?

Answer (score 0):

To add to BDL's comment, you can also try [GLIntercept](https://github.com/dtrebilco/glintercept) to validate that deletions are happening properly. This great tool will capture all OpenGL calls and works even if you're not using the core OpenGL profile.

You might be a victim of the task manager however. Taken from this [article on CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/BestPractices5.aspx?msg=3605652&display=Mobile#Avoidtaskmanagertodetectmemoryleak):

> The first and foremost task is to confirm that there is a memory leak. Many developers use Windows Task Manager to confirm if there is a memory leak in the application. Using Task Manager is not only misleading but it also does not give much information about where the memory leak is.
>
> First let’s try to understand how the Task Manager memory information is misleading. Task Manager shows the working set memory and not the actual memory used. So what does that mean? This memory is the allocated memory and not the used memory. Adding further, some memory from the working set can be shared by other processes / applications.

Make sure you confirm that you really have a leak. Then I suggest inspecting the OpenGL calls made by your app.